# how to store a function in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I wrote a function that checks the width of the window (for keeping a component responsive):

```
  handleResize = () => this.setState({ windowWidth: window.innerWidth });
  handleEvent = () => window.addEventListener("resize", this.handleResize);

  componentDidMount = () => this.handleEvent();
  componentWillUnmount = () => this.handleEvent();
```

In case I want to reuse this code in other files, is there any way I can save this code and just reuse it everywhere I want?

Comment: You can [Export and Import](https://javascript.info/import-export) almost anything in JavaScript.

Comment: why don't you use CSS media queries to keep components responsive?

Comment: @vsync That's another possible way, you're right.

Comment: @Jax-p Yes I just wanted to make sure how to handle a callback function when the function uses the "this"

Comment: @Commando As the other person commented, it is always better to use Media Queries for responsive designs, unless you're using something like that requires the `window` object. Have a nice day.

Comment: @Commando You want to recycle the content of callback also (to setState in any component where it is being called)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best way to do is using helpers. You can create a simple file, say `helpers.js` and place somewhere inside the `src` folder. It should contain something like this:

```js
export const HandleResize = callBack => window.addEventListener("resize", callBack);
```

In this above code, I have given a `callBack` parameter, because you're trying to access the state of the component that calls it. So you'll be sending it from the component.

And you can use it on your other files something like this way:

```js
import React from "React";
import { HandleResize } from "../helpers";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use helper functions like Praveen Kumar Purushothaman mentioned but in this case you probably want to use CSS media queries for it. Have a look into CSS modules. Also, your `this` might not refer to what you think you are referring when using an arrow function, if you still want to use `this` prefer to use the normal function defintion: `function () {...}`.